# Splitting whole map of Singapore into different postal sectors

Tags: qgis, mapping, postal-code, singapore

I am trying to construct a map like this below using QGIS (without the number overlay):

[image]

Currently, I have a full map of Singapore without the postal code.

[image]

Any tips for me to get started? I am using this software for the purposes of creating the map.

Comment: Do you have access to the postal code areas data or have purchased.

Comment: @Mapperz There is no need for me to access or purchase postal data because a mockup dataset is fine.

Comment: There would be a column consisting of the postal sectors(the numbers on the 1st image) and another column would be the sector name.

Comment: So the question is: how to split a polygon? Does this help? https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#split-features

Comment: I guess it helps. But is there a way to split it with precision?